# UnicodeDecodeError : invalid continuation byte in reading filenames in Python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, byte, decode

I went through all the various questions that were already posted here and tried the solutions mentioned but just couldn't get my code to work.

I am trying to read the filenames within directories using python but keep running into the following error.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 907: invalid continuation byte

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sklearn.datasets
import nltk

dataset = sklearn.datasets.load_files('data/', shuffle='False')
categories = dataset.target_names

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

for c in categories:
    directory_path = 'data/'+c
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(directory_path) if isfile(join(directory_path, f))]
    print ("Level 1 Intent : ", c)
    print ("---------------------------------------")
    for file_name in onlyfiles:
        file_path = directory_path+'/'+file_name
        with open(file_path) as f:
            first_line = f.readline()
            print("Level 2 Intent for ", c, " : ", first_line)

            stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
            from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
            stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
```

Though I get the output of the filenames printed as required, I run into this error message.

**Sample Output**

```
...
Level 2 Intent for  Presidents  :  Gerald Ford
Level 1 Intent :  Scientists
---------------------------------------
Level 2 Intent for  Scientists  :  Alessandro_Volta
Level 2 Intent for  Scientists  :  Michael_Faraday
Level 2 Intent for  Scientists  :  James_Watt
Level 2 Intent for  Scientists  :  Nikola_Tesla
...
```

**Sample Filenames**

```
1.clean
2.clean
S08_set3_a1.txt.clean
S08_set3_a8.txt.clean
```

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you add full traceback

Comment: I'm assuming you're using python 3. `with open(file_path) as f:` will open the file in text mode - which will implicitly assume the file content is utf-8 encoded, and will be decoded automatically when read. I guess [one of] the files you are opening is not actually utf-8, hence the error.

Comment: @TomDalton is there a way to check if any files are not of utf-8 while reading it and encode it?

Comment: The fact they raise `UnicodeDecodeError` is a pretty good sign! You will need to know what encoding they did use if you want to be able to decode them consistently. Are they definitely (entirely) text files?

Comment: You could also have a look at what the (binary) content of the file looks like around byte 907, and then take an educated guess as to what encoding is being used.

Comment: Yes. I have 58 files and all of them are text files

Comment: Could you add the content of the file that's failing - specifically the first 1000 characters or so?

Comment: None of the files are exactly failing. All the files' first lines are read and printed. But once all of them are printed, this error is thrown

Comment: @TomDalton You were right. Since there were so many samples, I wasn't able to identify if any files were failing. There was one file that was not of utf-8. I disregarded it from the test set and now things are working as desired. Thanks for all the pointers and guidance.